# Copy existing lambda functions from AWS to Github

Tags: github, aws-lambda

I have over hundreds of lambda functions in AWS and I need to make a Github repository containing all the lambda functions. 
How can I copy the lambda functions from the AWS console to my Github repository?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your local computer, or any other computer with access to both the AWS API and GitHub, write a shell script that calls [aws lambda list-functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html) to get a list of all your functions, and iterates over that list calling [aws lambda get-function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html), then uses the deployment package link in that response to download the actual Lambda deployment package. You would probably want to unzip each package into its own folder in your Git repository instead of committing the actual zip files. Finally do a `git push` to push all this to GitHub.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such shell script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @panchu.prodhan sorry no, I'm not here to do your job for you. If you are stuck on a specific part of this task post a question about that.